# How to add a custom func to existing protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift5, swift4.2

I have an UICollectionView, when I implement the UICollectionViewDelegate I get the functions provided by Swift for example:

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

In my UICollectionViewCell I put a **close icon** and I am looking for a way to add my custom **didCloseItemAt** function like this:

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didCloseItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Is this possible? how?

Comment: You can add it but no one is going to call it.

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own protocol which includes the UICollectionViewDelegate.

```
protocol YourCollectionProtocol: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didCloseItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
}
```

Then use this protocol instead of UICollectionViewDelegate.

Comment: What will that accomplish?

Comment: What he wanted to do.  Add something to a protocol.

Answer (score -1):

You can extend the protocol, and save yourself form having to write it everywhere.

```
extension UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didCloseItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
        // Write your code in here
    }
}
```

This is so powerful, now you can call this method in any object that conforms to UICollectionViewDelegate, and it will always run the code. You only need to write it once!